# AttributeError: 'Moments' object has no attribute 'date_published'

Tags: python, django

Well I have these models:

```
class Expression(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(name='Date Published', default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Moments(Expression):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

And I have another function or rather view function where i try to access the 'date_published' field
of a moments object like this:

```
expression.date_published.strftime("%H:%M %p, %d %B, %Y")
```

and I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Moments' object has no attribute 'date_published'
```

even though the date_published field is declared.
Please help.

Comment: how did you obtain the `expression` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu well its complicated I get an array of expression from another function and then I loop over them. I check whether the element is a Moments object or not and do certain operations.

Comment: Do you have all needed migrations after you inherit from Expression model? Try to run `manage.py makemigrations --check`

Comment: @SergeyPugach yes I have already migrated twice, but its showing no migrations to be applied